# Google has pending patent on my idea. What to do?

Tags: google, social-networking, news

[TizzToday](http://www.tizztoday.com/login/) is a news sharing social network which filters news based on their social importance.

It allows users 
    to connect all their social networks (facebook, twitter, linkedin, google+)
    to share news with a group of friends on the same news interest
    to add specific news sources to a Reader (our own news sources, or their own)
    to follow verified accounts (celebrities, personalities etc)
    to discover clustered news on our own news aggregator (1000+ news sources)

So it basically filters news from all the possible sources that a news might come from.

More than that, it allows users to customize the filter the way they want, so they have a personalized news feed that shows only the most relevant news for them.

To "Tizz" a news is our concept of Facebook's "Like" or Google+'s "+1". You can Tizz any worldwide news, or Tizz one directly from the aggregator, or your own news feed.

It is a great tool to discover interesting content which you can't reach by yourself.

Google submitted a [patent request](http://www.ipwatchdog.com/2013/11/19/google-seeks-patent-on-social-news-aggregator/id=46394/) AFTER I already finished the beta version of TizzToday. What will happen to my startup? Do you know anyone that can provide funding so we can take it off the ground?

Comment: I don't believe this is the place to ask for funding.  If by "finished the beta version" you mean "invited a bunch of people in to use it" then you may be able to use that as prior art.  If you just mean that you finished the code, but hadn't released it at all, you'll likely have to look for prior art elsewhere.